# dynamical sql, then pivot them, anything better?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

through dynamically SQL, I managed to got the result like this:

```
product   name
milk     AAA
tea      BBB
cake     CCC
milk     ABA
tea      BDB
cake     CAA
milk     xxx
tea     ...
```

I want to result like this

```
milk   AAA   ABA XXX ....   ...... (16 columns)
tea    BBB   BDB ...
```

looking at pivot example, it appears the column name already known, but I have 
16 columns, and not know the exact column name, any way can solve it. thanks

Comment: Google:  "<your database name> dynamic pivot".

Comment: also, I don't have the third column to aggregate. is it doable?

Comment: It would help to know which RDBMS you are using -- MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle -- they have different capabilities with pivoting.

Comment: it is SQL server, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since the dynamic column names aren't defined, they need to be generated.

Row_number can be used to add a sequencial number.

**Sample data**

> ```
> create table your_table
> (
>  id int identity primary key, 
>  product varchar(30) not null,
>  name varchar(30) not null
> );
>
> insert into your_table (product, name) values 
> ('milk', 'AAA'), 
> ('tea',  'BBB'), 
> ('cake', 'CCC'), 
> ('milk', 'ABA'), 
> ('tea',  'BDB'), 
> ('cake', 'CAA'), 
> ('milk', 'ABC');
> ```

**T-Sql:**

> ```
> DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
> DECLARE @DynSql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
>
> SELECT @Cols = CONCAT(@Cols+',', char(10), QUOTENAME(COL)) 
> FROM (
>    SELECT 
>    COL = CONCAT('Name_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY name)) 
>    FROM your_table
>    GROUP BY product, name
> ) q
> GROUP BY col
> ORDER BY col;
> -- SELECT @Cols as Cols;
>
> SET @DynSql = 'SELECT *' +char(10) 
>   + 'FROM (' +char(10)
>   + '  SELECT product, name' +char(10)
>   + '  , COL = CONCAT(''Name_'', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY name))' +char(10)
>   + '  FROM your_table' +char(10)
>   + '  GROUP BY product, name' +char(10)
>   + ') Src' +char(10)
>   + 'PIVOT (' +char(10)
>   + '  MAX(name) FOR COL IN ('+ @Cols +')' +char(10)
>   + ') Pvt';
>
> -- SELECT @DynSql as DynSql;
> EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSql;
> ```

> | product | Name_1 | Name_2 | Name_3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | cake | CAA | CCC | *null* |
> | milk | AAA | ABA | ABC |
> | tea | BBB | BDB | *null* |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=90044ae8470fc40ca89b378ab672c5e0)*